# Order of evaluation of names declared in class

Tags: c++, scope

There is this code:

```
#include <iostream>

const int c = 3;

struct A {
   static int f() { return c; }
   static const int c = 2;
};

int main() {
   std::cout << A::f() << std::endl; // 2
   return 0;
}
```

How does it happen that variable `c` defined **inside** class `A` is used in function `f` instead of variable `c` defined in global scope although global variable `c` is declared first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not a question of declaring order but of variable scope, the used variable are searched before in the current method/function after in the class/struct and a the and in the global context,
example:

```
#include <iostream>

const int c = 3;

struct A {
   static void print() { 
      int c = 4
      std::cout <<"Method Scope:"<< c << std::endl; // 4
      std::cout <<"Class/Struct Scope:"<< A::c << std::endl; // 2 here you can use alse ::A::c
      std::cout <<"Global Scope:"<< ::c << std::endl; // 3
   }
   static const int c = 2;
};

struct B {
   static void print() { 
      std::cout <<"Method Scope:"<< c << std::endl; // 2
      std::cout <<"Class/Struct Scope:"<< B::c << std::endl; // 2 here you can use alse ::A::c
      std::cout <<"Global Scope:"<< ::c << std::endl; // 3
   }
   static const int c = 2;
};

struct C {
   static void print() { 
      std::cout <<"Method Scope:"<< c << std::endl; // 3
      //std::cout <<"Class/Struct Scope:"<< C::c << std::endl; //is inpossible ;)
      std::cout <<"Global Scope:"<< ::c << std::endl; // 3
   }
};

int main() {
   A::print();
   B::print();
   C::print();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It does not matter which variable is declared first: if a class has a variable with the same name in it, that variable trumps the global variable. Otherwise you could get existing code in a lot of trouble simply by declaring a global variable with a name of one of its member variables!

Of course your class can use scope resolution operator to reference the global `c` directly:

```
static int f() { return ::c; }
```

Now [your program will print `3` instead of `2`](http://ideone.com/qhsfA6).

Answer (score 0):

imagine that you have long code which uses many variables, do you want them to be called instead these from a class to which function belongs? stating:

`a` or `b`

in class means

`this->a`

`this->b`

and if you want global variable to be visible you have to use it like

`::a` or  `::b` inside this function, so via:

```
static int f() { return ::c; }
```

From the standard docs, *Sec 3.3.1*

> Every name is introduced in some portion of program text called a declarative region, which is the largest part of the
>   program in which that name is valid, that is, in which that name may be used as an unqualified name to refer to the
>   same entity. In general, each particular name is valid only within some possibly discontiguous portion of program text
>   called its scope. To determine the scope of a declaration, it is sometimes convenient to refer to the potential scope of
>   a declaration. The scope of a declaration is *the same* as its potential scope **unless the potential scope contains another
>   declaration of the same name.** In that case, the potential scope of the declaration in **the inner (contained) declarative
>   region is excluded from the scope of the declaration in the outer (containing) declarative region.**

this means that the potential scope is same as the scope of the declaration unless another (inner) declaration occurs. If occurred, the potential scope of the outer declaration is *removed* and **just** the inner declaration's holds, so your global variable is hidden.